# How to embbed CSS into UIWebView on iOS

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview

I want to embed CSS into the UIWebview. This is how I've tried it:

```
<link href=\"example.com/common/css/common.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
```

This doesn't work. How can I load a CSS file into the WebView?

Comment: How are you loading the html file? With the whole string or are you reading from an imported html file?

Comment: Pleas show the code of `loadWebview`.

Comment: i want to load content of css file into UIWebView as color, style,... from link url href. But i cannot do it.

Comment: how are you loading your html? if you are reading through NSURL then your relative links should work without any code changes. Add code of webview load

Comment: yes, i am. i load file css from NSURL, but i don't know how to implement css file from NSURL into UIWebView. link URL contains in href=\"example.com/common/css/common.css\"